# Importing ZXing project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, zxing

I'm trying to import the ZXing project in Eclipse,

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

following this guide

http://knol.google.com/k/alec-go/modifying-the-android-barcode-scanner/2vd5zn6va2fqd/2#

But something went wrong. I can't debug or run the application because in every class this import is missing

import com.google.zxing.client.android.R;

I know that the R file should be generated by building the project but the building simply does nothing.I've searched for a solution for hours but I couldn't fine anything.

Obviously I've already tried to clean the project...

Comment: I think you should delete this import string and include correct import.

Comment: Nope, he needs to build the project with the Android SDK to build the R.java file. As you might expect, the project source code imports the right file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the project with Android SDK, whether on the command line with `ant` or via Eclipse. Then `R.java` will be generated for you.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was that I put the folder to import in the "WORKSPACE" folder, for any reason Eclipse can't import it in the proper way. So I moved the forlder to import and everything worked!! Thanks!!!